# Evaluating a function over the rows of a matrix

Tags: matrix

I performed quite a search, and I am unable to find a quick solution to the following problem.

I have a $p \times q$ matrix $c$, say

```
c = {{1 , 3}, {3, 4}}
```

and  function $f$, $\mathbb{R}^q \to \mathbb{R}$ say

```
f (x_, y_) := x + y
```

how to elegantly evaluate the function on the matrix's rows, $f[c_{11},c_{12}]$, $f[c_{21},c_{22}]$ and so on?

Thanks a lot

Comment: `f @@@ c` assuming you define `f` correctly. `f[x_, y_]:=x+y` that is.

Comment: Let me know if my comment or the linked answer are not solving your problem.

Comment: @Kuba, it does thanks a lot, I even tried but ade various syntax mistakes, any thanks again